# Serving custom errors for route constraint failures (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api

Got a Rails 4 application that has routes wrapped in a basic `ApiConstraint` class that checks that the user has the proper value for the `Accept` header:

```
# app/routes.rb
scope(module: "v1", defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: ApiConstraint.new(version: 1)) do
  # routes
end  

# lib/api_constraint.rb
class ApiConstraint
  attr_reader :version

  def initialize(options)
    @version = options[:version] || 1
  end

  def matches?(request)
    regex = /.../
    !!request.headers['Accept'].match(regex)
  end
end
```

That's all good, but I'd like a little more robustness with regards to error handling (a simple `true`/`false` coming from `matches?` isn't enough). Is it possible to somehow only do this check *once* and serve a proper `415 Unsupported Media Type` error? I say once because I think I see a workaround in just doing the check again at the bottom of `routes.rb` e.g.:

```
match '*any', via: :all, to: -> (env) do
  if env["HTTP_ACCEPT"].match(/.../)
    [415, {}, "{ \"error\": \"Bad Accept header or something ... \" }"]
  else
    [404, {}, [ApiErrors.not_found.to_json]]
  end
end
```

But that just seems really sloppy. I'd like to avoid using external stuff like faraday and whatnot. I feel like this *has* to be possible in Rails, and I'm just not sure of the syntax. All the other SO questions/blog posts I've looked at don't seem to mention this kind of functionality at all. Any response appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: My immediate thought is you could probably implement this as a middleware (which would essentially be taking your `match` block and sticking it in its own Rack app), or you could use a plain boring old `before_action` in `ApplicationController` since you have access to the `request` object.

Comment: Hmm...if doing it the middleware route is the only option, then so be it. Ah, forgot to mention I want to avoid the `before_action` route. Boring indeed, and doesn't quite fit design-wise to me.

Comment: I had two other thoughts. First is you could skip the constraints and use a Rack app (that responds to `call`) to handle all the possible errors. Or you could create an `ErrorsController` that specifically handles errors and can send back anything you want as well including the proper status code.